# Coming back from injury, advise on deadlifts

Tags: deadlifts, routine

Coming back from a car crash injury, was going to the gym a lot but had dropped deadlifts, recently re added to routine on light weights just as I know they are essential.

The injury was me shattering my kneecap, been advised to do leg extensions and things to strengthen my leg, however my gym does not have the leg machine. Find squats easy currently

Two questions for you all:

1: I did a light set two days ago (3x5 @70kg) on my upper day, Today I am doing lower, with squats, Should I do another light set of deads today on lower?

2: I did them the other day, and since them my metabolism seems to have gone through the roof, after one set is this correct? I usually drink 3 x 2L bottles of water over the space of work and the day, I find that my body feels always thirsty and that I want to consume them a lot quicker. (Not diabetic, blood sugar of 3.1)

Comment: Do you have any more details? i.e. what was injured/what rehab have you done/have you had medical advice on the safety of beginning deadlifting again etc. 1. In answer to point one, do you feel like you could squat? And is it in contravention to any of the above points. 2. Drink as much as you feel necessary to stay hydrated, and make sure you're getting the calories in to recover sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Form. Form. Form. Given the place of the injury and what you're trying to do, you should become a slave to your form from now on. Do weights that allow you to keep the weight, cheating it up or slight tweaks to get more weight may have been possible in the past, but now, as to not aggravate the injury or put unnecessary stress, make sure you reset your form ever single rep. That way everything is aligned and firing properly the same way.

Next comes the load, since you're trying to strengthen it, build-up, by 2.5, 5 to 10lbs or each side, every set, just to find where your form breaks down when you feel it about to break, go back about a step or two and call that your home for a while. Find a weight you can do 8 to 12 times comfortably for as many sets as you can. I prefer 5 sets of 8 to 12 at working weight. Every two weeks do that build up. Warm-up, get to your work out weight, do one set there, then go up by 5 or 10 lbs, do a set there and continue, till you feel the form breaking down, make a note of it and then do the process above. Be mindful of your knees, if they feel off don't deadlift, if you feel something weird while doing a deadlift, I would stop. At the end of the day your body will be your guide, listen to it and be overly cautious. There are other exercises that can help, Calf Raises, Leg Presses, Wall Squats, they can all help the knees.

Please note, I did not say to max out, I recommended that you reach a working set where your form starts to fail, meaning you will be far from your max weight. Given the injury, maxing out is probably not something you should risk. But the rest of the typical exercise regiments can be followed as long as the strictest form is applied to ensure you're not putting any undue stress on the joints.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you could squat then I see no issues. Obviously best to be careful with your knee.

No problem deadlifting twice a week either as far as I'm concerned, it all boils down to your recovery capacity (nutrition and recovery).

Comment: Maybe you should join your answers, so it's more 'in one place'. Also your answer is lacking sources and/or strong arguments. As it stands, it's only your opinion ('I see no issues' etc.).